# How are people testing rails 3.1 + force_ssl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The force_ssl function in rails 3.1 is hardcoded to ignore the development environment, but not test.  This is giving me redirect errors in my (minitest) tests. Is the solution to set up my test server to support ssl (if so, how?). If not, should I monkey patch force_ssl to ignore requests in test?

```
 def force_ssl(options = {})
        host = options.delete(:host)
        before_filter(options) do
          if !request.ssl? && !Rails.env.development?
            redirect_options = {:protocol => 'https://', :status => :moved_permanently}
            redirect_options.merge!(:host => host) if host
            flash.keep
            redirect_to redirect_options
          end
        end
  end
```

**EDIT** Found this chain, which confirms other people think this an issue, but doesn't look like there's a committed fix yet: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2630

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another option instead of monkey patching the entire application is to just override `force_ssl` in your test suite alone.  For example, in `test/test_helper.rb` you can add this:

```
# We don't want SSL redirects in our test suite
module ActionController::ForceSSL::ClassMethods
  def force_ssl(options = {})
    # noop
  end
end
```

Comment: this seems like a better approach

Comment: I have this at the end of my test_helper.rb file, and all is well running specs with spork. But just running rspec seems to ignore this. Any idea why?

Answer (score 17):

Here's another approach, if you don't want to mess with monkey-patching... you can use a before filter.  This is rspec, not minitest syntax, but you get the idea:

```
before(:each) do
  request.env["rack.url_scheme"] = "https"
end
```

This convinces your controller that it got an SSL request.

A benefit of taking this approach is that you can actually write a test to ensure your controller requires SSL. :)

Comment: Where did you put this? I get `NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `request'`

Answer (score 4):

That's what I ended up doing after recently upgrading to Rails 3.1 and switching to the `force_ssl` filter. Monkey patch to the rescue!

In a new file at `config/initializers/ignore_force_ssl_in_test.rb`

```
module ActionController
  module ForceSSL
    module ClassMethods
      def force_ssl(options = {})
        before_filter(options) do
          if !request.ssl? && !Rails.env.development? && !Rails.env.test?
            redirect_to :protocol => 'https://', :status => :moved_permanently
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, this works for me. I'm going to accept your answer, but if/when this gets incorporated into rails I'll come back and add a note

Comment: This will skip out any parameters in the URL, I'm pretty sure.  Look at this link to get around that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252910/rails-redirect-to-https-while-keeping-all-parameters

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in testing with varying SSL, I did this on the setup of the functional test.

```
def setup
  @request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is similar to [Kelly Sutton's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9021441/373522). I monkey patches `force_ssl` to ignore ssl requests in test environment, otherwise use the original rails implementation:

```
module ActionController
  module ForceSSL
    module ClassMethods
      alias_method :original_force_ssl, :force_ssl

      def force_ssl(options = {})
        unless Rails.env.test?
          original_force_ssl(options)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ryan's approach seems similar to this except his code only runs in the test environment. I think putting his block in test.rb is better than running your block in all environments?

Comment: Ryan's approach didn't work for me because `force_ssl` is a class method. spec_helper.rb will load the Rails environment first, then your code, thus effectively calling the original `force_ssl` and not the one defined in spec_helper.rb

Comment: This is the only solution posted here that worked for me. Rails 3.2.13 and Rspec with Capybara and Selenium. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This approach of Simon Carletti's works nicely:
http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.force_ssl = true
  end
end

# config/environments/test.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = false
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an answer in 2013. You can simply do:

```
force_ssl if: :ssl_configured?

  def ssl_configured?
    !Rails.env.test?
  end
```

Source: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

```
force_ssl unless Rails.env.test?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make test calls to app using ssl!

- use full uri with protocol `https://eample.org/my/route/here` in `get 'https://eample.org/my/route/here'`
- or use `https!(true)` and `https!(false)` to dynamically change behavior in INTEGRATION TEST

  ```
  https!(true)
  get "/users"
  https!(false)
  ```

For CONTROLLER you do not have to use SSL, because (I think) they directly call action as method, without routing and other transfer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Rails docs recommend using if: ssl_configured? with the force_ssl call.  You can then do:

```
   def ssl_configured?
    !Rails.env.development? && !Rails.env.test?
   end
```

Without having to monkey patch as official answer indicates.