# Rails redirect_to https while keeping all parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm redirecting to https like so:

```
redirect_to :protocol => 'https://', :status => :moved_permanently
```

However, the parameters don't go through like this. I can pass specific parameters through like this:

```
redirect_to :protocol => 'https://', :status => :moved_permanently, :param1 => params[:param1], :param2 => params[:param2]
```

How would I make it so that it just passes through every parameter on the url instead of having to explicitly declare each parameter?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
redirect_to({:protocol => 'https://'}.merge(params), :flash => flash)
```

This will keep all URL params through the redirect.

Answer (score 5):

With Rails 4.2 and above, passing the whole `params` hash will result in adding `?controller=foo&action=bar` to the querystring. Instead, you should do this:

```
redirect_to protocol: 'https', params: request.query_parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need this at the controller level, you can use:

```
MyController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl
end
```

You can use :only or :except if you only need this on a certain action. See documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html

Alternatively, if you just want your whole app to use ssl (assuming rails 3.1 or greater):

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.force_ssl = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just pass params as an argument like this:

```
redirect_to :protocol => 'http://', :status => :moved_permanently, :params => params
```

Comment: this would create `params[:params] => {:original => 'data'}`
rather than `params[:original] => 'data'`